# Simulation and Choice Table in R

Tags: r, loops, datatable, simulation

I am trying to replicate my data by generating some random data and putting it through a simulation in R. In this simulation, there is a weighted probability that certain sites will be favorable which is a function of depth. Density should be responding as the simulation proceeds.

Below is what I have so far:

```
nindiv=100
nsites<-c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Depth<-c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3)
Density<-c(0,0,0,0) #each site starts with 0 density
#I need to create a choice table that will be used for the statistical model
ChoiceTable=array(dim=c(nindiv*nsites,5)  # 5 columns, 1) the individual, 2) the site, 3) the choice (yes or no), 4) the depth and 5)the density

p1=1; p2=-.346
for (indiv in 1:nindiv) {
prob<-p1*Depth + p2*Density #this is the relative probability of each section being chosen
prob=prob/sum(prob)    #this makes sure that prob adds to 1

draw random number and let i be the section that is chosen
Save choice and density of each section at the time this fish made its choice  as input to the regression model something like  Thischoice=array(dim=c(nsites,5)

 ThisChoice[,1]=Index for this indiv  (eg 1,2,3,4)
 ThisChoice[,2]=seq(1,nsites)
 ThisChoice[,4==Depth
 ThisChoice[.5]=Density
 ThisChoice[,3]="no"  #set all sites up as "no"
 ThisChoice[i,3]="yes"  #then update the sites that was chosen
 Density[i]=Density[i+1]  #update density

 IF indiv is first fish set ChoiceTable=ThisChoice
 If indiv is not first paste ThisChoice to end of ChoiceTable

 end of loop over individual
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? Is there any error that you get?

Comment: You cannot use `nindiv*nsites` to set up the array because `nsites` is a character vector. Also `nsection` is not defined anywhere. You are assigning column 1 of `ThisChoice` which is not defined anywhere with a variable that does not exist: `Index`. You do not need to create 4 rows for each individual since each individual can be in only one site/section. You are computing only 4 probabilities, but there are 4 sites * 4 depths = 16 possible locations for each fish.

Comment: @RonakShah I am trying to draw random number that will select a site. I then need to save that choice (i.e., the site) and density value at the time the individual makes its choice.

Comment: @dcarlson I greatly appreciate you making me aware of the undefined variables and other issues in the code. I am just getting my feet wet in R and generating my own data and still have a lot to learn. Indeed, I only need 4 probabilities and 4 possible locations for each individual. Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to think about your problem. First set things up and create `Places` to hold the summary results and `Fish` to hold the individual results:

```
nfish <- 100
Sites <- LETTERS[1:4]
Depths <- c(.05, .1, .2, .3)
Density <- rep(0, 16)
Places <- expand.grid(Sites, Depths)
colnames(Places) <- c("Site", "Depth")
Places <- data.frame(Places, Density=rep(0, 16))
str(Places)
# 'data.frame': 16 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Site   : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
#  $ Depth  : num  0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 ...
#  $ Density: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
fill <- rep(0, 100)
Fish <- data.frame(ID=1:nfish, Choice=fill, Site=fill, Depth=fill)
str(Fish)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ ID    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ Choice: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ Site  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ Depth : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Now the loop:

```
# Weight for depth, p1 and weight against density, p2
set.seed(42)    # For Replicability. Remove this when you are simulating multiple events
p1 <- 2
p2 <- -.02
for (i in 1:nfish) {
     prob <- p1 * Places$Depth + p2 * Places$Density
     prob <- prob/sum(prob)
     choice <- sample(1:16, 1, prob=prob)
     Places[choice, "Density"] <- Places[choice, "Density"] + 1
     Fish[i, ] <- c(i, choice, Places[choice, -3])
}
```

And finally the results:

```
head(Places)
#   Site Depth Density
# 1    A  0.05       2
# 2    B  0.05       1
# 3    C  0.05       4
# 4    D  0.05       3
# 5    A  0.10       2
# 6    B  0.10       3
Places.tbl <- xtabs(Density~Depth+Site, Places)
dimnames(Places.tbl)$Depth <- sprintf("%3.2f", Depths)
Places.tbl
#        Site
# Depth   A  B  C  D
#   0.05  2  1  4  3
#   0.10  2  3  2  6
#   0.20  9 12  5  7
#   0.30 11 12 12  9 
head(Fish)
#   ID Choice Site Depth
# 1  1      8    4  0.10
# 2  2      3    3  0.05
# 3  3     14    2  0.30
# 4  4      6    2  0.10
# 5  5      9    1  0.20
# 6  6     12    4  0.20
```

Note that `Fish$Choice` is just the row number selected from `Places`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I was assuming that the output would show an uneven number of sites selected. For example, A,D,D,D,B,D,A,C with the associated densities and depth. My thought is that the most favorable sites are sites that have deepest depth but the increase of density controls the site selection of an individual. Also, each site should have a unique depth (A=0.05, B=0.1, C=2, D=4).

Comment: I was also looking for an output where the 100 individuals (i.e., 1,2,3,etc) were listed along with their choice (e.g., A,B,C, or D). There should be four columns 1) indiv, 2)choice, 3)depth, and 4)density. Thanks for your help!